# Javascript - Select checkbox by value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, selected

I made this code to select one checkbox when I click on a image but this don't work.

```
$linkToInterview = 'checkById(document.myform.checkbox,$interview_id)';
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='<?=$linkToInterview?>'><img src="<?=siteConfig::img_dir?>new_photos/video.gif" style="border:0px"/></a>
```

And Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkByID(chk,id) {
chk[id].checked = true ;
}
</script>
```

And checkbox code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$linkToInterview = 'checkById(document.myform.checkbox,$interview_id)';
```

will contain *literal* `$interview_id`, which means you're outputting

```
<a href="..." onclick='checkById(document.myform.checkbox,$interview_id)'>
```

To contain the *content* of `$interview_id`, you should use double quote, add a single quote around it, and use double quote on HTML output:

```
<?php
$linkToInterview = "checkById(document.myform.checkbox,'$interview_id')";
?>
<a href="..." onclick="<?=$linkToInterview?>;">
```

This will output (assuming your `$interview_id="test"`):

```
<a href="..." onclick="checkById(document.myform.checkbox,'test');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's just assume the problem is your javascript. The way you use JQuery should be similar to the way you use Javascript. The idea of this is whenever you click on the image, by passing the ID of the image --> you get ID of the equivalent checkbox (this depends on how you want to do it) --> trigger the checkByID function to do check/uncheck job for you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkByID(ID_Of_My_Checkbox) {
    $('ID_Of_My_Checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
     }
    </script>
```

Comment: What ID ? The value of checkbox ?

Comment: Your checkbox ID, <td><input type="checkbox" ID="ThisIsAnID" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>"

Comment: Remember to add reference at the top of your html file to use JQuery :D http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Yes I know this. I put that code on top of the page right ? When I click on the image I have to send the ID ... how I call JQuery function and send ID has argument ?

Comment: Updated with JQuery, don't work also:

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.8.2");</script>
   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkByID(ID_Of_My_Checkbox) {
        $('ID_Of_My_Checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
         }
    </script>

Comment: <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>" /></td>

    $linkToInterview = 'checkById($interview_id)';
    ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='<?=$linkToInterview?>'><img src="<?=siteConfig::img_dir?>new_photos/video.gif" style="border:0px"/></a>

Comment: You can edit to your question. Anyway, I spotted that your script src is pointing to google.com/jsapi? Shouldn't it be <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>